Как в Unity создать поле в инспекторе с пользовательским окном выбора
Я разрабатываю пакет для Unity для адаптирования интерфейсов (в основном) под разные темы и языки. Я уже написал классы для пользовательских UI-элементов, и мне надо сделать чтобы я мог в поле со строкой выбирать значение из путей которые есть в теме/языке как например в полях public Color m_Color;, public GameObject m_GameObject; или даже public AnimationCurve m_AnimationCurve. Вот класс для UI-изображения:
using Adapter.Styles;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Adapter.Elements
{
    [AddComponentMenu("UI/Adaptive/Image", order: 2)]
    public class Image : UnityEngine.UI.Image, IElement
    {
        [SerializeField] protected Setting m_Setting;
        [SerializeField] protected string m_Style;

        public Setting setting { get => m_Setting; set => m_Setting = value; }
        public string style { get => m_Style; set => m_Style = value; }



        public void Modify()
        {
            if (m_Setting != null && m_Setting.currentTheme != null && m_Setting.currentTheme.SearchStyle(m_Style, out ImageStyle imageStyle))
                imageStyle.Apply(this);
        }
        
        private void OnThemeChanged(string themeName, bool nameIsEmpty) => Modify();

        protected override void OnEnable()
        {
            base.OnEnable();

            if (m_Setting != null)
                m_Setting.ThemeChanged += OnThemeChanged;
        }
        protected override void OnDisable()
        {
            base.OnDisable();

            if (m_Setting != null)
                m_Setting.ThemeChanged -= OnThemeChanged;
        }

        protected override void Start()
        {
            base.Start();

            Modify();
        }
    }
}

Вот картинка что я имею ввиду, туда куда указывает красная стрелка надо что-то наподобие куда указывают зеленые:

Пример того что я хочу добиться:
[SerializedField, AddMiniButton(typeof(SomeCustomWindow))] protected string m_Style;

Желательно чтобы в этом поле можно было писать вручную но можно и как public Color m_Color; а я тогда в окне инспектора все реализую, сейчас я исследую метод EditorGUI.DoObjectField может что-то и найду.
PS: И еще вопрос, если у меня вдруг не получится реализовать такое поле самому по техническим причинам то как мне хотя бы получить иконки как на этих полях: кружочек или например пипетка как на цветовом поле. Я уже очень много спрашивал у ChatGPT но он мне пишет класс с полем с текстурой а не получение этих иконок. Получилось только что-то с иконками ошибки, предупреждения и информации но они для другого нужны были.
PSS: Как можно создать окно только с кнопкой закрыть. Я когда то в Visual Studio создавал проект и там я как-то создавал окно у которого был только крестик на панели сверху. В Unity такие окна есть на как раз этих полях дл выбора объектов или цвета.

Кстати я не против кода на c++ если это единственный вариант.


demo.settings.item это ваще чё? Это не путь! Каталогизация в билде, за исключением Resources в Unitiy своя, из-за чего пути не имеют смысла. Выбрать то чё надо? Чё из себя представляет этот твой Style? Это просто ключ? А где они тогда описываются?

PS: пытаться создавать всё с нуля используя картинки редактора это путь в никуда. Код и ресурсы редактора в dll и прямого пути не существует. ChatGPT может много с чем помочь, с кодом на C# или любом другом популярном языке, но в целом он нихера не знает о Unity, а уж о его специфических фичах, как кастумный редактор и его внутреннем устройстве тем более.

Кстати в самой Unity есть примеры меню выбора для string полей, похожее на меню выбора компонента из каталога типа Rendering/2D/Light 2D. В New Input System в компоненте On-Screen Button, Control Path это string, каталог выбора для которого собирается из ассетов инпутов в проекте.

PropertyAttribute, для него PropertyDrawer. В его Rect рисуете поле и кнопку. Можно попробовать EditorStyles для красоты. А по нажатию кнопки показываете что-нибудь, от GenericMenu до EditorWindow.

Да, Style это просто ключ (ну или путь но в контексте тем/языков), ключи (там структура из вложенных контейнеров) для стилей прописываются в файле тем (ScriptableObject). Темы (и языки) указываются в файле настроек (Setting : ScriptableObject) и как видно в коде потом получение стилей происходит.

И вопрос, EditorStyles (конкретно EditorStyles.objecrField) сразу сделает поле таким же например как public GameObject gameObject или мне еще придется там пиксель в пиксель вымерять всë и цвета корректировать. И кстати можно пример как эти стили применять, если я правильно понял их на место для опций надо (не помню точно как там но наподобие такого EditorMethod(..., GUIOption[] options))

EditorStyles это просто стиль. У объекта могут быть ширина, высота, мин ширина, макс высота, выравнивание, веса, цвет, текстура, края, текст, шрифт, размер и т.д. всё как в css, это вообще не про функционал, а поле в инспекторе это целый набор объектов. И да, в этих стилях так-же стили содержащие те самые текстуры иконографии редактора Unity, но пытаться из этого что-то собрать это ужасная идея.

Если это ключи, коих не сотни, то проще отображать поле в виде выпадающего списка.
public class StyleFieldDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override VisualElement CreatePropertyGUI (SerializedProperty property)
    {
        var options = GetOptions();
        var field = new PopupField<string>(property.displayName, options, property.stringValue);
        field.BindProperty(property);
        return field;
    }

    // Поскольку все стили это ScriptableObject, 
    // то эти ассеты можно найти и собрать список всех ключий.
    private List<string> GetOptions ()
    {
        List<string> options = new List<string>();
        var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:MyStyleObjectType", null);
        foreach (string g in guids)
        {
            string path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(g);
            var style = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(path) as MyStyleObjectType;
            if (style != null)
                options.Add(style.Key);
        }
        return options;
    }
}


С тем-же успехом можно отображать поле в виде объекта, хотя хранит оно только string.
public class StyleFieldDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    private SerializedProperty _property;

    public override VisualElement CreatePropertyGUI (SerializedProperty property)
    {
        // Не совсем уверен что можно хранить ссылку на сериализуемое свойство.
        _property = property;
        
        var field = new ObjectField(property.displayName);
        field.objectType = typeof(MyStyleObjectType);
        field.value = GetStyle(property.stringValue);
        // В идеале нужно подписываться при AttachToPanelEvent 
        // и отписываться при DetachFromPanelEvent от всех событий.
        field.RegisterValueChangedCallback(OnChange);

        return field;
    }

    private void OnChange (ChangeEvent<Object> e)
    {
        if (e.target == null)
            _property.stringValue = "";
        else
            _property.stringValue = (e.target as MyStyleObjectType).Key;
    }

    private MyStyleObjectType GetStyle (string key)
    {
        var guids = AssetDatabase.FindAssets("t:MyStyleObjectType", null);
        foreach (string g in guids)
        {
            string path = AssetDatabase.GUIDToAssetPath(g);
            var style = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(path) as MyStyleObjectType;
            if (style != null && style.Key == key)
                return style;
        }
        return null;
    }
}


п.с. код написа на коленках и не факт, что работает.

Как написать атрибут для поля, показано в PropertyDrawer.

ну по факту этих ключей можно создать сотню и больше (для стилей там немного но для переводов да), они как в minecraft bedrock в файлах переводов там идет ключ=значение и так для любого текста для которого нужна локализация и поэтому я хотел сделать имеено открывающееся окно (ChatGPT мне уже выдавал строковое поле на которое кликать можно с последующим открытием окна и с кнопкой справа но не как в инспекторе (обычная кнопка с троеточием)). Кстати с выпадающем списком и GenericMenu я с самого начала попробовал но я хотел поиск добавить, щас поизучаю EditorStyles

По поводу PropertyDrawer у меня там есть много пользовательский отрисовщиков так что я знаю как их делать.

Насчет того как создать окно только с крестиком как при открытии например выбора цвета. У меня получаются только окна с кнопками Разверенуть/Свернуть, Скрыть и Закрыть.

И еще, если нужна дополнительная информация по реализации можете глянуть проект на гитхабе: https://github.com/FruitGames537/Adapter

UI Toolkit позволяет легко менять визуальный стиль всего интерфейса в игре. Localization пакет для Unity тупо уже существует. Ты пытаешься создать резиновое колесл из глины и палок, не занимайся хренью.

Я свое хочу, я же спокойно смогу внедрять всë новые и новые функции.

С вероятностью в 99.99% эти функции там уже есть, а если и нет, то никто не запретит их добавить.

Ну а я все свое хочу, и вопрос изначально не об этом был.

Я потом для дополнений этот пакет возможно слелаю чтобы можно было аддоны и моды на игру писать. А так я могу прямо в код внедрить и ни писать никаких надстроек.
